# Structuring Code to handle Authentication

Tags: php

I'm developing code which will be responsible for creating new users and modifying existing ones via an API in a user management system.
I have the authentication class developed, which handles authenticating the API user via username/password, and returns a cookie which gets stored as a property in the authentication object.

The cookie needs to be sent along with any API call, but I'm not sure of the best approach to structure this.

Do I inject the Authentication object into the multiple User classes responsible for modifying and creating users for them to call the Authentication->getCookie() method; or, is it best for each User class to instantiate the Authentication object and call the methods to authenticate and return the cookie; or is there a better method.

Comment: If those User classes only need the cookie, why not simply pass it in to them?

Answer (score 1):

Cookies used to handle **Session** abstraction, not the **User** objects. You can store **User** object in **Session**. PHP has a good session management functions and a lot of session management libraries, you should not write your own. I use symfony http_foundation component for session management in my projects.

http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php
http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

Every user can have multiple sessions from different devices with the same credentials. I use many to one relation to store them in database (many **Sessions** to one **User**). Also you need to use strong random in cookies to prevent cookie spoofing, PHP can handle this part too.

Best practice: use community driven libraries based on builtin functions with strong protection algorithms.

Authentication class should be service(or factory) to manage Sessions and another class (Controller) to manage users. You should strongly separate this functions for good architecture. In my projects i use **SessionManager**, **UserRepository** and **UserController** classes for basic user management.

Further reading: **RBAC** / **ACL**. Good luck!